# Вывести вместо даты слово "вчера"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, дата

Не получается вывести "вчера", с "сегодня" и остальными датами проблем нет.

Что не так делаю?

```
showMessageDateTime(dateTime) {

    let today = new Date(),           // присвоение и форматированние текущей даты
        yesterday = today.getDate() -1,             // присвоение и форматирование текущей даты - 1 день
        roomLastMessageDate = new Date(dateTime);           // присвоение и форматирование даты последнего сообщения комнаты

    if (dateTime) {
        if (today == roomLastMessageDate) {                                                                
            return 'Сегодня'                                                                                
        } else if (yesterday == roomLastMessageDate) {                                                     
            return 'Вчера'                                                                                  
        } else {                                                                                            
            return roomLastMessageDate;                                                                     
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь проблема, что я всегда попадаю в первое условие(getFormattedDate-функция форматирования даты в нужный формат(дд.мм.гг))

```
                let today = new Date(),                                                               
                    yesterday = new Date(),                                                        
                    roomLastMessageDate = new Date(dateTime);                                                   

                yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() -1);

                if (dateTime) {
                    if (getFormattedDate(today === roomLastMessageDate)) {                                                                
                        return 'Сегодня'                                                                                
                    } else if (getFormattedDate(yesterday === roomLastMessageDate)) {                                                     
                        return 'Вчера'                                                                                  
                    } else {                                                                                            
                        return roomLastMessageDate;                                                                     
                    }
                }
```

Comment: две разные даты, но отображается "Сегодня"...

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `==` не нужно этого делать. Сравнивать нужно через `===`.
2. `today.getDate() -1` не вычитает 1 день. Нужно писать так:

   ```
   yesterday = new Date()
   yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() -1);
   ```
3. Чтоб сравнить теперь дни, можно использовать `getTime`, сбросив предварительно часы, минуты, секунды.

   ```
   dropHMS(date){
       date.setHours(0);
       date.setMinutes(0);
       date.setSeconds(0, 0);
   }

   showMessageDateTime(dateTime) {

       let today = new Date(),           // присвоение и форматированние текущей даты
           yesterday = new Date(),             // присвоение и форматирование текущей даты - 1 день
           roomLastMessageDate = new Date(dateTime);           // присвоение и форматирование даты последнего сообщения комнаты

       yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() -1);

       dropHMS(today);
       dropHMS(yesterday);
       dropHMS(roomLastMessageDate );

       if (dateTime) {
           if (today.getTime() === roomLastMessageDate.getTime()) {                                                                
               return 'Сегодня'                                                                                
           } else if (yesterday.getTime() === roomLastMessageDate.getTime()) {                                                     
               return 'Вчера'                                                                                  
           } else {                                                                                            
               return roomLastMessageDate;                                                                     
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: `вы сравниваете ссылки, а не значения` - это утверждение более чем не верное на корню. Просто оператор обычного сравнения `==` преобразует  к числам, из-за этого, может просто не отличать: `пустые строки, строки нули, false, true, null, undefined`... А вот  оператор строгого равенства `===` проверяет равенство без приведения типов. Итог: оператор  `===`, делает код более очевидным. Это должен знать каждый.

Comment: @And я просто посчитал, что использование `==` автором было не осознанным.

Comment: Спасибо, убрал === потому что подумал, что из-за него не работает)

Comment: @Pavel42rus вы в `showMessageDateTime` что передаёте и что это значит `getFormattedDate(today === roomLastMessageDate)` (вы же тут `bool` передаёте в `getFormattedDate`)?

Comment: сори если не туда правки внес...

Comment: @Suvitruf дату вида гггг-мм-дд чч:мм:сс

Comment: @And конечно так-себе авторитетный источник, но все же https://i.imgur.com/rKxyGJa.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, самое что нужное, это то. что `===` делает код. более очевидным, остальное не важно. А то, что использовать оператор `==` не нужно или нельзя - это не есть хороший совет. Его можно использовать, если вы уверены, что у вас не летят пустоты и разные типы которые он может не отличить от действительности.

Comment: @And я больше про сравнение по ссылкам